# C return chars using recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to create a function that gets a char array, and if the element in the array is a letter and lowercase it changes the element to uppercase, and so the opposite.

I debugged the code and it seems to work, my only problem is that I don't know how can I rebuild the char array, because every time I return a single char and it suppose to create a char array, from what I understand.

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
char reverseLetter(char str[])
{
    char temp;
    if (strlen(str) == 0)
        return 0;
    if (str[strlen(str) - 1] >= 'A' && str[strlen(str) - 1] <= 'Z')
    {
        temp = tolower(str[strlen(str) - 1]);
        str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
        return reverseLetter(str) + temp;
    }
    else if (str[strlen(str) - 1] >= 'a' && str[strlen(str) - 1] <= 'z')
    {
        temp = toupper(str[strlen(str) - 1]);
        str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
        return reverseLetter(str) + temp;
    }
    else
    {
        str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
        return reverseLetter(str);
    }
}

void main()
{
    char str[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'C', '\0' };
    printf("%c", reverseLetter(str));
}
```

EDIT:
I thought I need to return each char apparently that's not what you suppose to do, you need to change the element in the array and return the array.

Comment: Why would you do this with a recursive function? The problem is iterative.

Comment: What does it print? What do you want it to print instead?

Comment: Is the function supposed to modify the string in place or return a pointer to a new string? In either case, you need to think about the return type. Having it be `char` instead of `char*` or `void` is problematic.

Comment: They asked us to do it with recursive function so it's not really my choice.

Comment: I am with AKX. But if there is the usual reason (i.e. "teacher said so") then please double check that they want a return value of a single char. That is because the goal would be easy with a pointer to char and make didactical sense.

Comment: @Yunnosch they want us to return a string, but there are no strings in C so I figure he mean char array, simply, it should print ABC

Comment: Yes, I thought so. But then the shown prototype is wrong and it should indeed NOT be a single char. See answer by meaning matters. Please [edit] your question. To fix that. The answer is non-recursive however and hence not what you need.

Comment: I edited the question, apparently you're NOT suppose to just return char, you do need to change the element with a pointer like AKX did.

Comment: "return the array" doesn't really make sense in C. You have to think carefully about who allocates the memory for the array (either the function or the caller) and either pass a pointer to the memory that the caller allocates or return a pointer to the memory that the function allocates.

Comment: you're right, I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do this recursively, here's a recursive function that toggles the case from A to Z *in place*.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void reverse_letter(char *p) {
  char c = *p; // dereference pointer to get the value
  if (c == 0)
    return; // found end-of-string, nothing more to do
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
    *p = tolower(c); // flip case and assign
  } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
    *p = toupper(c); // flip case and assign
  }
  reverse_letter(p + 1); // Call with pointer to next character
}

int main() {
  char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'C', '0', '9', 0};
  printf("%s\n", str);
  reverse_letter(str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The output is

```
abC09
ABc09
```

Comment: Use `isupper(int c)` and write `*p = isupper(c) ? tolower(c) : toupper(c);`.

Comment: This assumes that `p` can be modified.

Comment: I missed the recursiveness. My mistake.

Comment: @meaning-matters Yes, it does. That's why it's not e.g. `const char *p`. Also, `isupper`/`toupper`/`tolower` may have different semantics than this code, depending on the locale in effect.

Comment: @AKX: "tail recursion" does not mean "a recursive call to a function which happens to be located at the end of the function". C does not support tail recursion through function call syntax. Your recursive call is consuming stack space and will fail due to stack overflow if there are enough characters in the target string. If you want to make it "tail recursive" you'll need to A) replace the argument `p` with an updated value and B) branch to a label at the beginning of the function. Not complex, but interesting from an implementation standpoint.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica The first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call disagrees IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the user create a new string, and give it to you as parameter:

```c
char reverseLetter(char *dest, char const *source)
{
    while (*source)
    {
        if (*source <= 'z' && *source >= 'a')
            *dest = *source - 'a' + 'A';
        else if (*source <= 'Z' && *source >= 'A')
            *dest = *source - 'A' + 'a';
        else
            *dest = *source;
        ++dest;
        ++source;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char src[] = "abC09";
    char dst[6];

    reverseLetter(dst, src);

    printf("%s --> %s\n", src, dst);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `source` has qualifier `const` so the user knows that you won't modify the source string.

If you absolutely want it to be recursive:

```c
char reverseLetter(char *dest, char const *source)
{
    if (*source <= 'z' && *source >= 'a')
        *dest = *source - 'a' + 'A';
    else if (*source <= 'Z' && *source >= 'A')
        *dest = *source - 'A' + 'a';
    else
        *dest = *source;
    if (*source)
        reverseLetter(dest+1, source+1);
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch it is now

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite your code to something equivalent:

```
char str[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'C', '\0' };
char c = reverseLetter(str);
printf("%c", c);
```

The above is exactly the same, so it should be obvious why it could never work. You're returning a single character and printing a single character.

I would use this approach. First, I'd create a function to flip a character:

```
char flip(char c) {
    if(isupper(c)) return tolower(c);
    return toupper(c);
}
```

And then the recursive function is simple:

```
char * reverseLetter(char str[]) {
    if(str[0]) {
        reverseLetter(str+1);
        str[0] = flip(str[0]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

And then in main:

```
int main() {
  // Zero terminator not necessary. It gets appended automatically.
  char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'C', '0', '9'}; 
  printf("%s\n", str);
  reverseLetter(str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```